# Select non null value column from two columns in odata query

Tags: c#, odata

I am joining two tables like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Student s 
JOIN Department d ON d.StudentId = s.StudentId 
WHERE s.studentname = 'John'
```

But sometimes there is null value in `StudentId` column of the `Student` table. In that case I have to join with `StudentSubId` column. In SQL we can use `COALESCE` like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Student s 
JOIN Department d ON d.StudentId = COALESCE(s.StudentId, s.StudentSubId)
WHERE s.studentname = 'John'
```

Now I have to apply `COALESCE` like feature in OData query while joining the two tables. Currently my OData query is joined based on only `StudentId`.

Any help?